# Can't reconnect CDMA modem

Tags: usb-modem

I have Novatel MC760 CDMA modem.

I plug it in ubuntu 14.04 and have to wait 60-120 seconds and after that Network Manager lists that device if I click icon or type in terminal

```
$ nmcli dev
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
ttyUSB0    cdma              disconnected 
wlan0      802-11-wireless   connected    
eth0       802-3-ethernet    unmanaged
```

I see network connection that I called CDMA

I can connect to it almost instantly.

In terminal I type

```
nmcli con up id "CDMA"
```

and it works.

I can disconnect with

```
nmcli con down id "CDMA"
```

But I can't connect again by typing `nmcli con up id "CDMA"`

I have to unplug and plug and wait 60-120 seconds for device get listed in `nmcli dev`

Any ideas how to get it working after disconnection without manually re-pluging and waiting?

Answer (score 1):

Try `wvdial`. It prints more verbose information.

Comment: Yes. wvdial works and I can re-connect now. I will wait a bit more for other answers as wvdial is not 100% smooth. I would like Network Manager to handle all networking in one place without opened terminal windows.